# Is it legit or scam

Tags: bank-account

Can I be paid easily through giving somebody else my login details and access to it while I have moved all what I got in to another account

Comment: There is no legitimate reason why someone would need your login details. It is a scam.

Comment: Ah yes, this is exactly how I transact at the grocery store; they give me their register and I put money in there.

Answer (score 6):

They don't need your login to send you money. Once you give them your login they can do anything they want to your bank account. They can lock you out. They can use it to make an illegal transaction.

Plus they may try it on other sites they think you use.

They can send you a check to give you money. Then you can deposit the check. Of course you do have to make sure the check is legitimate.

Comment: Forget locking you out, making an illegal transaction; they can just log in and send all your money to them!